# Returning a recursive output as a list

Tags: python, recursion

It's my first question so I'm sorry for any mistakes.

I'm trying to find all combinations of K from N using recursion.
and have this code:

```
   def k_size_subsets(n, k):
    list1 = [i for i in range(1, n + 1)]
    data = [0] * k
    help_fun(n, k, data, list1,0,0)

def help_fun(n, k, data, list1,index, i):
    if index == k:
        more_help(data)
        return
    if i >= n:
        return
    data[index] = list1[i]
    help_fun(n, k, data, list1, index +1, i+1)
    help_fun(n, k, data, list1, index, i+1)

def more_help(list):
    str1 = ''
    for i in range(len(list)):
        str1 += str(list[i])
    print(str1)

k_size_subsets(5, 3)
```

The output I'm looking for is a list like this:
`["123","124","125","134","135","145","234","235","245","345"]`

so far the function outputs the right answer but as a string.

```
123 124 125 134 135 145 234 235 245 345
```

How can I return it as a list?

Thank you!

Comment: Your functions don't even `return` anything!! Try to use `return` instead of `print( )`

Comment: sorry! I tried messing with the code around a little and left the print there. It was 'return' in the original. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, just replacing this one `print( )` with a `return` is not enough. I suggest leaving the `print( )` in your question, and taking a look at j1-lee's answer below for how to fix it. (But don't edit your question with the fix! Otherwise it's very confusing.)

Comment: PS: I assume your goal here was to practice with python and recursive functions; but if you're really interested in getting all those k-size subsets, there is a function in python's standard library that does exactly this: [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). Example use: `from itertools import combinations; print(' '.join(''.join(c) for c in combinations('12345', 3)))`

Comment: @Stef Per your comment above, which I agree with, I have edited the question back to its original form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to let the functions pass variables each other, e.g., as lists, rather than printing inside the functions. The following is a minimally modified version of your code:

```py
def k_size_subsets(n, k):
    list1 = [i for i in range(1, n + 1)]
    data = [0] * k
    return help_fun(n, k, data, list1,0,0)

def help_fun(n, k, data, list1,index, i):
    if index == k:
        return [more_help(data)]
    if i >= n:
        return []
    data[index] = list1[i]
    return help_fun(n, k, data, list1, index +1, i+1) + help_fun(n, k, data, list1, index, i+1)

def more_help(lst):
    str1 = ''
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        str1 += str(lst[i])
    return str1

print(k_size_subsets(5, 3))
# ['123', '124', '125', '134', '135', '145', '234', '235', '245', '345']
```

Comment: In addition to your minimal modifications, could you please also choose another name for `more_help`'s parameter? So as not to encourage shadowing builtin `list`. I suggest calling the parameter `data` instead.

Comment: @Stef Good point, I've edited the answer.

Comment: you guys are great! thanks. But only if I print the function it prints out a list...is there a way for the function to return a list only by calling it?

Comment: @OldFashion12213 You could write a separate `print_list` function which prints a list in a way that you find more pretty. For instance, `def print_list(l): print(' '.join(l))`

Answer (score 0):

Here you just have a single `print` statement, but here are a couple of solutions of possible interest, but which could help to turn all the output into a list even if you have multiple print statements in different places, while still minimising the change to the overall structure of your code.

Option 1) Use a list in the module scope called `_output`, and in place of any `print` statement, append to that list.  This avoids having to pass other variables around between your functions.  Note the use of `clear()` to empty the list before starting.

```
_output = []

def k_size_subsets(n, k):
    _output.clear()
    list1 = [i for i in range(1, n + 1)]
    data = [0] * k
    help_fun(n, k, data, list1,0,0)
    return _output

def help_fun(n, k, data, list1,index, i):
    if index == k:
        more_help(data)
        return
    if i >= n:
        return
    data[index] = list1[i]
    help_fun(n, k, data, list1, index +1, i+1)
    help_fun(n, k, data, list1, index, i+1)

def more_help(list):
    str1 = ''
    for i in range(len(list)):
        str1 += str(list[i])
    _output.append(str1)

print(k_size_subsets(5, 3))
```

Option 2) Turn your function into a generator.  If in every place where you have a `print` statement, you turn it into `yield`, and you change the calls to use `yield from`, then you could do something like this.  Note the list comprehension in the caller to actually iterate and build a list.

**Warning: this solution looks very similar in terms of the syntax, but involves some more advanced concepts.**

```
def k_size_subsets(n, k):
    list1 = [i for i in range(1, n + 1)]
    data = [0] * k
    yield from help_fun(n, k, data, list1,0,0)

def help_fun(n, k, data, list1,index, i):
    if index == k:
        yield from more_help(data)
        return
    if i >= n:
        return
    data[index] = list1[i]
    yield from help_fun(n, k, data, list1, index +1, i+1)
    yield from help_fun(n, k, data, list1, index, i+1)

def more_help(lst):
    str1 = ''
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        str1 += str(lst[i])
    yield str1

print([x for x in k_size_subsets(5, 3)])
```

Comment: The generator solution is good, but I really can't see any upside of using a class here. What is this class supposed to represent?

Comment: @Stef It provides a way to share data between the functions (here, the output list that is being built), without having to change the function signatures (aside from adding "self"). But I will change it to put a list as a module variable instead.

Comment: @Stef Now done.